Adding Error Bars to Multi-Panel Multiline Plot Using Matplotlib
I made a panel of 4 line plots, each plot contains multiple lines.
I am trying to add error bars to each line in the plot and I can't seem to make it work.
x is of dimension (23,)
y is of dimension (23,6)
yerr is of dimension (23,)
Here is the code:
labels = ["F2 Training","F5 Training","Mix Training","All Training"]
sublabels = ["Control | F2 Parents","Control | F5 Parents","at F2 | F2 Parents","at F5 | F2 Parents","at F2 | F5 Parents","at F5 | F5 Parents"]

fig, axs = plt.subplots(1,4,figsize=(20, 4))
axs = axs.ravel()
for trn in range(0,4):
    y = pd.DataFrame(allYs[trn])
    std = pd.DataFrame(allSTD[trn])
    x = np.array(x)
    y = np.array(y)
    axs[trn].errorbar(x,y,yerr=std)
    axs[trn].set_title(labels[trn])
    axs[trn].set_xticks(x, labels=x_lab,rotation=90)
    axs[trn].set_ylabel("Gain")
fig.legend(sublabels,loc='center right', bbox_to_anchor=(0.5, 0., 0.5, 0.5))

ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 1)

I have attached a picture of the plot without the error bars.
Thank you in advance for any ideas or insights.
I tried to add error bars following the documentation and continue to get errors
